# No primes for increments for factorial n

Tags: elementary-number-theory, solution-verification, prime-numbers, prime-gaps

I was reading the following exercise:

> Prove that if $n \ge 2\space$ then among the numbers:   $n! + 2,
> \space n! + 3,..., n! + n$ none are prime (where $n! = 1\cdot 2 \cdot
> 3 \cdot ... n$

My approach:
Let $k \in {2, 3, 4...n}$
Then for any number $n! + k$ we have that $k | n! + k$
This is because $k | n!$ since $k$ is a factor of $n!$ (belongs to one of the products) and $k | k$.
So we have the positive integer: $$\frac{n! + k}{k} = \frac{n!}{k} + \frac{k}{k} = \frac{n!}{k} + 1 = c + 1$$ where $c = \frac{n!}{k}$
Now we know that $c$ is a positive integer, we also know that $c + 1 > 1$ and that $c \ne  n! + k \space$ hence there is another number that divides $n! + k$ besides $1$ and $n! + k$ and so the number $n!+ k $ can not be a prime.

Is this a correct approach?

Comment: Your working is completely correct, but you don't need to make it so complicated. $2 \le k \le n$ implies directly that $k$ divides $n! + k$. Hence $n! + k$ is not prime because $k$ is a factor. Job done.

Comment: I agree, the whole part after "So we have the positive integer" seems repetitive.

Comment: @PrimeMover: To me it wasn't obvious without that thought process. Perhaps there is something I am missing?

Comment: @PrimeMover: How does 2≤≤ directly imply that?

Comment: @Jim In order show that $n! + k$ is a composite number, all you need to do is show that it has *any* divisor that is not either $1$ or $n! + k$. The demonstration that $k$ is such a divisor is instant and easy, as you showed. And while it is an interesting exercise to show what the other factor is, that is, the one you multiply $k$ by to get $n! + k$, it is **not necessary** to do that to prove that $n! + k$ is composite. Perhaps I should have written this as an answer.

Comment: @PrimeMover: `it is not necessary to do that to prove that !+ is composite` I still am not clear on why or how it is obvious. It isn't to me

Comment: @Jim A (positive) number $p$ is prime if and only if the *only* positive numbers it is divisible by are $1$ and $p$. So, if you find *any* number that is *not* either $1$ or $p$ which *is* a divisor of $p$, then that means $p$ is not prime.

Comment: @PrimeMover: Yes that is the approach I used for my solution. But you mention it has redundant aspects but you haven't explained or I wasnt able to understand what is the redundant part. I suspect something is obvious to you, that you assume it should be or it is to me too.

Comment: Really all you need is that a prime less than $n$ divides $k$, so all values from $k=2$ to $k=\mathrm{nextprime}(n)-1$ are composite.

Comment: @Jim I can't work out what you're not getting. All you need to do is show that $n! + k$ is not prime for $2 \le k \le n$. You don't need to know what the factors actually *are*, you just have to show that *they exist*. And once you know that $k$ is a factor, then you *know* that $\dfrac {n! + k} k$ is *also* a factor, because *that's how factors work*. But from the purposes of this exercise, you are not being asked to work out what the other factor actually is.

Comment: @Jim basically, to do that problem you have to prove that $n! + k$ for $2 \leq k \leq n$. For every such $k$, you know that you can factor out $k$ from both terms and hence the result so obtained is divisible by $k$. So it's clearly proven that none of them are prime.

Comment: @PrimeMover: "then you know that $\frac{n!+k}{k}$ is also a factor, because that's how factors work" this part I did not realize. I think I get it but is there some formal description of these rules for factors?

Comment: @Jim It's your basic bog standard definition of multiplication as learned in school. Let $n$ be composite. Then *by definition of composite number* it can be expressed as $n = r \times s$ for some $r$ and $s$, where $r$ and $s$ are integers. This is the basic definition of what a factor is. So if $n$ has some $r$ as a factor, then there *must* be some integer $s$ such that $r$ times $s$ is equal to $n$. That is what $n = r \times s$ means.

Comment: @PrimeMover: yes but how does show that $r + x$ is a factor of $n$ as you pointed out earlier for $\frac{n! + k}{k}$? That is the part I am losing you

Comment: @Jim What $r + x$? Now you've lost *me*. Let's start again. You know that $k$ is a factor of $n! + k$. So that means the other factor is $\dfrac {n! + k} k$ because $k \times \dfrac {n! + k} k = n! + k$. **But you don't need to bother to work that out, because all you want to do is prove that $n! + k$ is composite, and all you need to do in order to do that is show that $n! + k$ has a factor which is not $1$ and not $n! + k$.**

Comment: You have already established $k\mid n!+k$ with $k\ge 2$. $k$ must be a proper divisor since $n!$ is a positive integer and hence $n!+k>k$. This implies that $n!+k$ cannot be prime. It is really that easy. If $n!+k$ were prime, the only positive divisors would be $1$ and $n!+k$ , but $k$ is another one.

Answer (score 1):

There has been extensive discussion regarding the answer in the comments, but nevertheless I will add an answer for the future readers.

The sequence of numbers you have consider are as follows

$$2!+2 \qquad n=2$$
$$3!+2,\space 3!+3 \qquad n=3$$
$$4!+2,\space 4!+3 ,\space 4!+4 \qquad n=4$$
$$\vdots$$
$$n!+2,\space n!+3,\space \cdots n!+k,\space\cdots, n!+n\qquad n=n$$

Now, we know, $n!=1\cdot2\cdot3\cdots n$. Clearly, for $k<n$, we can write $n!$ as $n!=1\cdots k\cdots n$ where $n\in\{2, 3, ..., n\}$. Hence we can write $n!+k$, where k is defined as before, as $$k\bigg((1\cdots(k-1)\cdot (k+1)\cdots n)+1\bigg)$$

Clearly, $k(<n)$ divides $n!+k$. Thus, none of $n!+2,\space n!+3 ,\space n!+(n-1)$ are prime because they have $k$ as a factor.

And for $n+n!$, the result follows almost trivially!